# SpriteKit touchesBegan not working as suggested

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a simple game that ads money when you tap. I am just getting started with SpriteKit and through it would be good to start simple. I am having a small problem though. If you would refer to the code below

```
var starterMoney = 0

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    starterMoney + 5
    print(starterMoney)
}
```

This only prints out 0 everytime. The code runs but it will never print 0 + 5 and so fourth. I am curious as to why this would be a problem. I am new to SpriteKit so I may not understand the functions very well but I feel like this should be working just fine. What am I doing wrong; can anybody assist me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `starterMoney + 5` to

`starterMoney += 5`

or

`starterMoney = starterMoney + 5`

depending on which makes more sense to you